# OpenShift: Create volume in replication controller - why?

Tags: openshift, replication, volume

The [OSCP documentation](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.6/dev_guide/volumes.html) for handling volumes in version 3.6 shows an example for adding a volume to a replication controller: `oc volume rc/r1 --add --name=v1 --type=secret --secret-name='$ecret' --mount-path=/data`

...why? I cannot think about one situation where a replication controller needs a mounted volume, no matter if it has a secret or not. In my previous OpenShift experience the replication controller was more or less a stand-alone entity which doesn't interact with anything except the pods it manages. But since this example is from the official documentation, i am curious where the need of a mounted volume, with a secret or not, could emerge from.

Can someone please give an example where this could be useful? I am especially wondering because an image update or deployment update would create a new replication controller - which has no added volume, then.

Comment: Would only make sense to me if you weren't using a DeploymentConfig but had created the ReplicationController yourself directly.

Answer (score 1):

The example predates StatefulSets and so was showing how to add a volume to a pod managed by an RC for something stateful.  The example should be updated to focus on more modern Kubernetes patterns for state.